# Add priority columns by refering to each col information

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following tables , I would like to distinguish each cols by null or is not null.

```
priority1 priority2 priority3 ...
a          a        null
a          null     null
null       null     null
a          null     a
a          a        null
null       a        a
null       null     a
null       a        a
```

so my desired result is like this , I would like to set priority and I would like to add `priority_rank` as follows.

```
priority1 priority2 priority3 ... priority_rank
a          a        a             1
a          a        null          2
a          null     a             3
a          null     null          4
null       a        a             5
null       a        null          6
null       null     a             7
null       null     null          8
```

I tried following.

```
select case 
when priority1 is not null and priority2 is not null and priority3 is not null then priority_rank=1,
when priority1 is not null and priority2 is not null and priority3 is null then priority_rank=2,
・・・
```

But my concern is that when the priority column increase, this case increase exponentially, so that from now on 2^^3 = 8 select clause are needed.

Are there any easy ways to achieve this ?

If someone has opinion,will you please let me know. Thanks

Comment: For the not null values, is it always the same value, i.e. 'a'?

Comment: not null value is not always same value. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there can be different values ​​in the priority columns, and the higher the value, the higher the overall priority, and that the rows with the same priority values should have the same `priority_rank` value in the results, you just can use `DENSE_RANK` with `ORDER BY` for all priority values in descending order. Since PostgreSQL uses `NULLS LAST` for ascending ordering by default, than with descending order `NULL` values would appear first. To prevent this you need to add `NULLS LAST` to all order statements.

Finally, your query can look like this

```
select 
    *, 
    dense_rank() over (
        order by priority1 desc nulls last, 
                 priority2 desc nulls last, 
                 priority3 desc nulls last
    ) priority_rank 
from priorities
```

For the sample data you provided the output is

| priority1 | priority2 | priority3 | priority_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | *null* | 1 |
| a | a | *null* | 1 |
| a | *null* | a | 2 |
| a | *null* | *null* | 3 |
| *null* | a | a | 4 |
| *null* | a | a | 4 |
| *null* | *null* | a | 5 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | 6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=54536f5b5e789cfa0a3f9c8920598c54)*

Answer (score 1):

My apologies I was able to create this on SSMS with pretty basic ANSI SQL so I think it might work.  It will still need some maintenance if you add more columns.

```
SELECT
*
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS PRIORITY_RANK
FROM
(
SELECT 
        Priority1
      , Priority2
      , Priority3
      , ISNULL(LEN(Priority1),0) + ISNULL(LEN(Priority2),0) + ISNULL(LEN(Priority3),0) AS TotalPriority
      
  FROM PriorityTableTest

) AS X

ORDER BY TotalPriority DESC, Priority1 DESC, Priority2 DESC, Priority3 DESC
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thanks for the heads up I removed those brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `DENSE_RANK()` function as the following:

```
Select priority1, priority2, priority3,
       DENSE_RANK() Over (Order By Case When priority1 IS NOT null Then 1 End,
                                   Case When priority2 IS NOT null Then 1 End,
                                   Case When priority3 IS NOT null Then 1 End
                         ) priority_rank
From table_name
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=470ccd9d34180fb2e0e5ffe3dd962667).

Note that null values are sorted last in the default ascending order.

Answer (score -1):

`ORDER BY` + `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` sort and assign rank

```sql
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY priority1 IS NULL,priority2 IS NULL,priority3 IS NULL) AS priority_rank
FROM table_name
ORDER BY priority1 IS NULL, priority2 IS NULL, priority3 IS NULL
```

Comment: The ordering is not correct, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e1c8e4f5f3b8a13d479a70e6e7fc56d6